# Синоним [htaccess] к [.htaccess]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

86 вопросов помечено тегом [htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess)
456 вопросов помечено тегом [.htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess)

Следует создать синоним, что бы избежать ручного редактирования вопросов.

Comment: Если плюсанёте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413715 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413246 , то смогу добавить запрос на синоним. :)

Comment: Кажется рейтинг по тегам пересчитывается раз в сутки, скорее всег завтра сможете добавить запрос на синоним

Comment: Да, похоже, придётся ждать до завтра, не даёт добавить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синоним [добавлен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/synonyms).